# Kleene Math Logic, p. 45, ex. 11.1

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

From Kleene Math Logic, p. 45, ex. 11.1

Infer $\Gamma, A\vee B\vdash A\rightarrow C$ from $\Gamma \vdash A\rightarrow C$ in the proof of V-elimination by two methods: directly from the definition of "deduction"; by use of Theorem 9.

I can't get how to do it in both cases. Is it possible to add any assumption to the left side of the $\vdash$ symbol ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first method, the answer is Yes.

From the definition of *deduction* (page 35 and comment page 37) we have [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_of_entailment), i.e.

> if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma' \vdash \varphi$, for $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$.

Regarding Th.9, consider $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n \}$; this is not restrictive, due to the fact that a formal deduction is a *finite* list of formulas (page 35).

Applying 9(i) we have: $\Gamma, A \lor B \vdash \gamma_1, \ldots \Gamma, A \lor B \vdash \gamma_n$.

But $\Gamma \vdash A \to C$ means: $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n \vdash A \to C$ and thus, applying 9(ii) we have: $\Gamma, A \lor B \vdash A \to C$.

Comment: so I even can add $\neg P$ and $P$ as assumption, can't I ?

Comment: @user142248 - YES

Comment: Thanks, Mauro!!!